# Why does Chrome send user credentials with preflighed CORS request?

Tags: google-chrome, credentials, cors

The [w3.org CORS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight0) explicitly states that user credentials should be omitted when making a preflighed request with CORS:

> Exclude user credentials.

Why does Google Chrome neglect to do this?

Take a look at the following code.

```
var url = 'http://example.net/resources/test.php';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
```

Here are the request headers from the above scenario.

```
OPTIONS /resources/test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.net
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://elsewhere.example.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/17.0.963.79 Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin
Accept: */*
Referer: http://elsewhere.example.net/cors-example.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: somecookies=here
```

As you can see, the cookies (user credentials) *are* sent along, in spite of the CORS specification. Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: I only came across this question today, but in the mean time, I rediscovered the same problem and reported it in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. You can file a bug report with Google: [new.crbug.com](http://new.crbug.com)

Comment: Thanks. I filed a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121904

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a reason.  You specifically told the XHR that it should include credentials by setting the property:

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

Remove that line and Chrome should make the request without the cookies.